# Middle mouse click in VirtualBox (Vista host, Debian guest)

Tags: linux, windows-vista, virtualbox, debian

I'm running Virtualbox on Windows Vista.  I have a Microsoft USB mouse (it says "Comfort Optical Mouse 3000") with left and right buttons, and a mousewheel in the middle.  If I press down on the wheel, it pretty obviously makes a "click".

I'm running Debian inside Virtualbox, and it's working great, but middle-mouse-click does nothing.  Left and right click, and scrolling with the wheel, work fine.

Is there any way to get middle-mouse-click to work in my virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which desktop environment you're using, but look in your mouse preferences for a setting for "emulate three button mouse". I believe you should turn that off.

Comment: I've never seen such a feature at any layer higher than the X server, and I haven't turned it on there.  The X server logs say it's using driver "/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/vboxmouse_drv.so", and "ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: Found 9 mouse buttons".

Answer (score 1):

It could be a configuration issue on the host, especially if you have MS Intellipoint software installed. Try the mouse settings in Control Panel.

Comment: What setting would I be looking for?  I've never seen any middle-mouse-button related anything in MS Windows, except that IE can use it to turn on the funny scrolling mode (which works here).  I certainly don't see any setting that looks like "unbreak my middle mouse button pls".

Comment: @Ken: with Intellipoint installed, the first tab of Mouse Properties lets you configure the buttons. The default action of the middle button is to open "Instant Viewer" (a bit like Mac Exposé), in which case the foreground app doesn't receive a middle click.

Comment: I've never heard of Intellipoint, and if it isn't part of Vista SP2 (and I don't see anything by that name here), then I don't have it.  Do I need that for the middle button to work in apps other than IE?

Comment: @Ken: on the start menu it's called "Microsoft Mouse". You don't need it for the middle button to work.

Comment: OK, I definitely don't have that.  Thanks for the idea, though.